# How show transformation result in write to log step in pentaho?

Tags: pentaho

I have a transformation [parameter] that send a row to result, how can I show the result rows in the write to log?Like how we do with variables

[image]
[image]

I want to create a log like:

Parameter of result:

- par_1: value
- par_2:value
  Parameter of job:
- par_job_1: value
- par_job_2:value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I don't understood the question. Why not use "Write to log"?

[Write to log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gLNn.png)

Comment: I want to put a write to log in the job that will produce a list of all result parameters

Comment: Given your screenshot @DevScheffer, you are putting the Write to Log step in the job, not in the transformation producing the parameters.

Comment: Yes, because the job also has some parameters that I want to include in the write to log